# Node creation with parameters

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I have a form that when submitted and validated, needs to be redirected to a page to create a node (node/add/factura-tmn), but I want to send a parameter to this page. Is it possible?

I currently have the following code:

```
function add_invoice_file_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/add/factura-tmn';
  drupal_redirect_form($form_state);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solucion is very simple:

```
function add_invoice_file_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
// files validations...
...
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/add/factura-tmn/' . $fid;
  drupal_redirect_form($form_state);
}


function paperless_planning_form_node_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if(isset($form['type']) && isset($form['#node'])) {
        $type = $form['#node']->type;
        switch($type) :
            case 'factura_tmn':
                $fid = arg(3);
                $file = file_load($fid);
                ...
        endswitch;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a modified node add form? You can change it to have whatever fields and validation you want.

Comment: I can not, because I have to send a file before it can create the node. I wanted to send the "fid" to create the node.

Comment: You could make a file a required field. Otherwise you could put the fid at the end of a custom callback which gets the node add form.

Comment: can not create any field, because the file the first form is an xml file which may contain some values the following form (node/add/factura-tmn). even need to send the "fid".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process a form, you can use [drupal_form_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7). The example reported in the documentation page shows how to use the function.

```
// Register a new user.
$form_state = array();
$form_state['values']['name'] = 'robo-user';
$form_state['values']['mail'] = 'robouser@example.com';
$form_state['values']['pass']['pass1'] = 'password';
$form_state['values']['pass']['pass2'] = 'password';
$form_state['values']['op'] = t('Create new account');
drupal_form_submit('user_register_form', $form_state);
```

Inside a form submission handler, it's not necessary to call `drupal_redirect_form()`; the code just need to set `$form_state['redirect']`. See what is done from form submission handlers implemented by Drupal core modules, such as [system_modules_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.admin.inc/function/system_modules_submit/7), [aggregator_form_opml_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--aggregator--aggregator.admin.inc/function/aggregator_form_opml_submit/7), and [comment_multiple_delete_confirm_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.admin.inc/function/comment_multiple_delete_confirm_submit/7).